# Problema al seleccionar valor de nodo en documento XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Necesito asignar el valor de un elemento de un documento XML a una variable, específicamente el valor del elemento de nombre  `Clave` ,escribí esto pero no funciona ya que no encuentra el nodo debido a que la función no devuelve valor alguno...que estoy haciendo mal...??

```
  public string ValoresCamposXml(XmlDocument documentoXml)
  {
      string valores = string.Empty;
      XmlNode nodo = documentoXml.SelectSingleNode("//Clave");
      valores = nodo.InnerText;
      return valores;
  }
```

este es el documento xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<FacturaElectronica xmlns="https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Clave>50627031800310140886100100001010000000003112465302</Clave>

<NumeroConsecutivo>00100001010000000003</NumeroConsecutivo>
<FechaEmision>2018-03-27T08:00:20-04:00</FechaEmision> 
-<Emisor>
<Nombre>TECNOLOGIAS SA</Nombre>
-<Identificacion>
<Tipo>02</Tipo>
<Numero>310rty14088uyt61</Numero>
</Identificacion>
<NombreComercial>TECNOLOGIAS SA</NombreComercial>
-<Ubicacion>
<Provincia>1</Provincia>
<Canton>02</Canton>
<Distrito>01</Distrito>
<Barrio>01</Barrio>
<OtrasSenas>CENTRO CORPORATIVO PLAZA ROBLE EDIFICIO LAS TERRAZAS 5TO PISO</OtrasSenas>
</Ubicacion>
-<Telefono>
<CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
<NumTelefono>40701540</NumTelefono>
</Telefono>
-<Fax>
<CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
<NumTelefono>40701540</NumTelefono>
</Fax>
<CorreoElectronico>brojas@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
</Emisor>
</FacturaElectronica>
```

Comment: no funciona.. quiere decir que no lo encontras o tira un error? porque la doble // delante de clave?

Comment: No funciona significa que no lo encuentra,no devuelve ningun valor

Comment: Eso es parte de la sintaxis XPath

Comment: Efraín, tus preguntas suelen tener esos `-` antes de algunos nodos... ¿Será posible que intentes que no aparezcan en tu XML? De esa forma es más sencillo responder

Answer (score 2):

Si te animas a utiliza linq to xml es muy simple de acceder a valor de la clave.

Algo como esto

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

                        <FacturaElectronica xmlns='https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>

                        <Clave>50627031800310140886100100001010000000003112465302</Clave>

                        <NumeroConsecutivo>00100001010000000003</NumeroConsecutivo>
                        <FechaEmision>2018-03-27T08:00:20-04:00</FechaEmision> 
                        <Emisor>
                        <Nombre>TECNOLOGIAS SA</Nombre>
                        <Identificacion>
                        <Tipo>02</Tipo>
                        <Numero>310rty14088uyt61</Numero>
                        </Identificacion>
                        <NombreComercial>TECNOLOGIAS SA</NombreComercial>
                        <Ubicacion>
                        <Provincia>1</Provincia>
                        <Canton>02</Canton>
                        <Distrito>01</Distrito>
                        <Barrio>01</Barrio>
                        <OtrasSenas>CENTRO CORPORATIVO PLAZA ROBLE EDIFICIO LAS TERRAZAS 5TO PISO</OtrasSenas>
                        </Ubicacion>
                        <Telefono>
                        <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
                        <NumTelefono>40701540</NumTelefono>
                        </Telefono>
                        <Fax>
                        <CodigoPais>506</CodigoPais>
                        <NumTelefono>40701540</NumTelefono>
                        </Fax>
                        <CorreoElectronico>brojas@gmail.com</CorreoElectronico>
                        </Emisor>
                        </FacturaElectronica>";

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); 


        XNamespace xmlns = "https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2017/v4.2/facturaElectronica"; 

        var clave = doc.Descendants(xmlns + "Clave").First().Value;


        Console.WriteLine(clave);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pude obtener el valor de los elementos de un xml usando esta linea de codigo:

```
XmlNodeList nodo = documentoXml.GetElementsByTagName("NombreDelNodo");
```

esta me devuelve uuna lista de los elementos con el nombre especificado, y puedo acceder a sus valores mediante la posicion que ocupan en la lista..por ejemplo:

```
string valor = nodo[0].InnerXml;
```

un ejemplo mas detallado aparece aqui :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk.aspx